# Comments to flagged answers not shown

Tags: feature-request

At the moment this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373212/how-do-i-use-nagios-to-monitor-a-log-file/4811633#4811633) has spam flags, but when looking at the link in the answer I don't think that is justified so I added a comment under the answer to that effect and I've seen other people do similar with other flagged answers/questions.

However, with the new flags screen, it is possible for people to flag questions/answers as spam without actually going to the message in question, so the comment won't be seen. I think it might be useful in these instances if there was some way of disagreeing with the flags. Either by making a comment visible on the flags screen in some way or by raising an anti-flag that would show up there. Even if the anti-flag might not actually decrease the flags, it would be useful as an indicator to the people moderating to not just flag without checking first.

Comment: +1 I have flaged it to and added an comment,

Comment: Can't you "unflag" it via the moderation tools? Maybe it's better feature to request... :)

Comment: @Shadow: Well, I'd assume that `unflag` could possibly be misused if some 10k user wants to protect his own posts but if it's just flagged that someone disagrees, people can make up their own minds.

Comment: The misuse can be avoided by not letting people unflag their own flagged question or answer.

Comment: I prefer the idea of commenting on flags within the 10k tools.

Answer (score 1):

This suggestion, while well-intentioned, seems unnecessary to me. Have you seen this become a problem in practice?

Although I haven't had access to the 10k tools for very long, and I only have them on MSO, I thought it was pretty clear that the flags tab is **not** supposed to be the only way that flags are checked. All the flags come with links to the posts they're for, so reviewers *can* see them in context. I thought it was understood that it was the reviewer's responsibility to use those links, and that the quick "agree with this flag right now" options are only for the truly egregious cases.

I know, I know, "common sense isn't common," and all that jazz, but by the time they reach 10k, people should be able to be trusted to not be total sheep when it comes to looking into flags. If that's not the case, then frankly, our community/site has bigger issues.

Comment: Well, the answer I linked to was flagged as spam in the end, even though both me and one other user left comments saying that we thought it wasn't. (Though there was also a comment left by a low-rep user that might be disagreeing with my comment, I'm not sure how to read it). Obviously I can't say for sure if that was due to people disagreeing with me or if they didn't look at the comments.